# State Variable Storage in Contracts

Tags: solidity, local-variables

I'm learning Solidity. According to the [docs](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/structure-of-a-contract.html#state-variables), variables are permanently stored in contract storage. From my understanding (I may be wrong), the details are on the blockchain. My question is, how do I look at this? I was looking at [EtherScan](https://etherscan.io), however, I couldn't find anything. I'm learning this by writing contracts in Remix. While I know those contracts are on TestNet, I'm not sure which one (Ropsten, Kovan, or Rinkeby). I'm also not sure where the contract address is in Remix. I've successfully created my contract. But, I don't see an address anywhere.

I'm I simply overlooking something or am I way off in my understanding? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, variables are stored in the blockchain with thetransaction you sent to it, for the contract to be deployed. If someone need to retrieve a value or change a value in the storage he may have to use a getter or setter function related to the variable which cost another transaction (getter functions may not need a transaction to be mined ).

For a smart contract to be appear in the blockchain you need to deploy by sending a transaction and once the transaction is mined a message like contract `deployed at 0x13......` will be displayed which is the contract address.